# Failed to call method

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We've got this MongoDB Mongoose query:

```
sampleSchema.find({
    $where: "expired <= " + (new Date())
  })
  .limit(9)
  .sort({
    postedDate: -1
  })
  .then((docs) => {
    console.log('found docs ', docs);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error ', err);
  })
```

This query always goes to the `catch` block and the error thrown is:

```
{
  "name": "MongoError",
  "message": "Failed to call method",
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "Failed to call method",
  "code": 1,
  "codeName": "InternalError"
}
```

What is the problem with this query?

Comment: Try `{expire: {$lte : (new Date())}`.

Comment: @Titus It worked as expected, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: wouldn't it be nice to mention what went wrong in the error message? "InternalError" is barely helpful

Comment: @asgs The error message is from MongoDB. We don't control it

Comment: @student I was referring to the MongoDB developers who generate this error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sharing for future readers:

This did the trick:

```
{expire: {$lte : (new Date())}
```